# How to handle autoloading with composer by keeping the WordPress naming conventions?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, composer-php

I'm a bit confused because I'm programming a plugin for WordPress by using composer as it's the real way to go.

So I've created a composer file inside my plugin and some other stuff. In the composer file I've added my namespace for autoloading:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Johnny\\Lolkick\\": [
      "includes/classes/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Inside my classes folder I've created now a class with the name `class-main.php`. I've decided to take this name because of the WordPress naming conventions:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#naming-conventions

The class by itself was named `class Main {`. Inside my base plugin file I've created now a new instance of my class which failed. After changing the file name to `Main.php` it worked.

So in result the WordPress naming convention broke the autoloading of composer. I want to know now how do you handle this problem? How should I keep the naming convention by using composer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your code base is not compatible with [PSR-4 autoloading](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), a [psr-4](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) mapping inside your composer.json's autoload section won't work, as you noticed.

I'd say you have two choices here:

First one would be to use [`classmap`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) instead:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["includes/classes/"]
    }
}
```

This would simply parse all the files recursively within that folder and map the classes to their names, no matter what naming scheme you're following.

Second one would be to build your own autoloader, and use [`files`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) to have it loaded automatically:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["includes/autoloader.php"]
    }
}
```

That autoloader would have to define what should happen (which class should be loaded, or not) when referring to a given class name.

In both cases, don't forget to run [`composer dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-) afterward.

Comment: @MrJo Did this help at all...?

Comment: I tried it out today and it worked! Thanks a lot :) I was some days off so sorry for the late response

Comment: @Mr.Jo What you opted ?  `classmap` or  custom autoloader  ?